# Setting response headers in Laravel 4.2 while using layouts/views

Tags: php, laravel-4, http-headers, response

I am using layouts in the following manner in my controllers as described in the docs (Note that nothing is returned):

```
public function someControllerFunction () {

    $this->layout = View::make('layout');
    $this->layout->content = View::make('page', $params);

}
```

In my layout I set some `cache-control` headers like so:

```
<?php
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=600');
    Log::info("headers set in layout");
?>
```

This is all fine and dandy and these headers are present in the response for all pages in the app. However now I have a page which I want to explicitly disable caching with:

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    Log::info("headers set in View");
?>
```

I tried placing this in my View, but no cigar. Looking at the logs the php in the View is execute *before* that in the layout, resulting in the layout definited headers overwriting the View definied headers.

So I decided to look for the "Laravel" way of doing it and found the docs suggest you return a response like so:

```
return Response::view('page')->header('Cache-Control', '...');
```

But how do I make a response that uses layouts? I can't find any mention of it in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You can make and pass a layout into Response (attaching the headers to the response) and return it like so:

```
$this->layout = View::make('layout');
$this->layout->content = View::make('page', $params);

$response = Response::make($this->layout);
$response->header(...);

return $response;
```